# Change physical keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard

I want to use my Filco Convertible 2 TKL keyboard with swedish layout on my Samsung S8, but cannot get any other layout than US. I want Swedish.

The other questions I could find in here did not help.

Here is my Settings menu for physical keyboard:
[image: physical keyboard menu]

I've also seen the Swiftkey help and tried their suggestion, to no av. Their input menu shows nothing related to layout, beside a link to the Android options.

As you can see I have four input there, three stock android languages, and Swiftkey. I've tried both the stock swedish, and Swiftkey in swedish. The shortcut menu says that switching language is done with shift+enter. That does nothing more than putting an actual space in my text.

---

Edit: I've now removed the stock keyboards from the **non physical** keyboard, and they also disappeared from the physical keyboard menu (which is strange, but ok). I now have nothing more than Swiftkey, both for on-screen and physical keyboards. In Swedish. Still, the physical keyboard writes with US layout.

Comment: You could try [External Keyboard Helper](https://android.izzysoft.de/images/playstore_icon.png) (it also has a [gratis demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo) to try out, though that hasn't been updated for a while).

Comment: @Izzy thanks! It didn't help though. I've got the app, it's high up in the "Physical keyboard" settings menu, in Swedish. Still US layout. One thing is the "Language and input"->"Default keyboard": it's stuck on SwiftKey. I also see the External Keyboard Helper, and Samsung keyboard as alternatives, but these are not selectable.

Comment: Sad to hear it didn't help (but at least was worth a try). But glad to see you solved your issue, congrats! And that without needing an extra app. All the better!

Comment: External Keyboard Helper did the trick for me. I know this thread is old, but next time, post screenshots, how you configured External Keyboard Helper. Why don't you put "Swedish" for all the keyboards?

Comment: @Quidam I want the auto-complete in all three languages.

Answer (score 3):

The solution involved deactivating all keyboards from the **on-screen** keyboard options.

After doing so, the only one that was left (as on-screen) was also the only one left in physical. Even SwiftKey Swedish (not External keyboard helper) now works.

With several possible keyboards in on-screen, I still cannot select which one is default (the options show up with radio buttons, but are not selectable), but I think I can live with it.